# SVG font scaling appears different depending on viewer application

Tags: gimp, inkscape, text, svg

I have created an SVG image using Inkscape which consists of a QR code, with some text below the QR code.

[image: Image as intended, and as seen in Inkscape, Google Chrome, and Inkview]

Before I submit the image to the manufacturer that will be in charge of printing the image onto some physical objects, I tried viewing the image in some different programs such as GIMP and Firefox, and to my surprise the text below the QR code in certain programs does not scale to the width of the QR code, as seen in this image:

[image: QR code as displayed in GIMP and Firefox]

As can be seen, there is a significant amount of space to the right of the last digit of the ID. However, in Inkview/Google Chrome the image appears precisely as it does in Inkscape.

Having done some research, it appears that some programs do not implement SVG text properly. While ultimately I will have to consult with the manufacturer and coordinate based on how their systems interpret the image, I am curious:

**Which programs are typically used to verify that an SVG image is rendered correctly?** For example, since the image is made in Inkscape, I would ideally like to crosscheck the image with another program to verify the output.

I have read other places that I could try to convert the text to a path for better compatability across programs, however this text is being generated dynamically so this does not seem practical. (Note that the problem is not a result of generating the text dynamically, as I have verfied the same behavior using static text elements.

**Update with link to SVG files:**
You can find a Plunkr that includes both the template and the "filled-in" template here: https://plnkr.co/edit/MZXmkkfrkztImOlzABrv

Don't mind the hole to the right that is missing in the generated version - that is just for measurement reference in Inkscape.

Comment: Can you provide a sample file for testing?

Comment: Hi Michael, see updated post with link. I had to remove the first image due to reputation constraints.

Comment: If you want to make this easy for people who might be able to help, please provide the SVG files.

Comment: Hi Michael, as far as I can tell, SVG files cannot be attached - even as images, therefore the link to the plunkr where both images can be seen between the <svg> tags.

Comment: Possibile workaround would be to convert the thext to a path, then it will scale the same everywhere. This is especially true if you use some exotic font the end device might not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to print these then you are much better served by *PostScript* (PS) than *SVG*. *PostScript* engines have better quality checks than *SVG*. But more than that *PS* actually defines printer color spaces something that *SVG* does not do well at this point, not that most viewers would even begin to support this.

Regardless of format issues you should be talking about the manufacturing with the manufacturer. Not us, so the only way to iron out manufacturing issues is to talk with your manufacturer about their requirements and software used, not speculate on what they use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The manufacturer requires SVG for printing - in this case black and white. I have settled on another solution, but will mark this as the answer, insofar as how text in SVG is rendered on the screen appears to be implemented at the whim of whatever viewer application is being used.